# Looping through 2 separate directories using Java & in Bash

Tags: java, loops, directory

I'm writing a script that selects one folder in directory1 named f2 and crosschecks the names of all of the folders in directory2 for a match, and if true, it copies f2 from directory1 into a subdirectory of f2 (the folder of the same name) located in directory2. At this moment, I'm experimenting with Java implementation using Apache Commons, however I'm more concerned with the bash implementation, and this is what I have so far:

Java Implementation:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

private String src = "";
private String dest = "";

private void setName(String source, String destination) {
    src = source;
    source = destination;
}

private String getSrcName() {
    return src;
}

private String getDestName() {
    return dest;
}

private void loop() {
    File srcDir = new File("\\IGSASCEWGSHARDY\Common Services\Data Management Unit\Surface Water\Field Notes (historic)\ ");
    File destDir = new File("\\IGSASCEWFSZEUS\DataArchive\Surface Water\Data Sites\ ");

        for(int i = 0; i < Files.list(Paths.get(srcDir)).count(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Files.list(Paths.get(destDir)).count(); j++) {
                if(srcDir.getSrcName().equals(destDir.getDestName())) {

                    FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
                    j = 0;
                    System.out.println("Same!");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not same!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my batch file implementation:

```
::@ECHO OFF
::setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%i in ("\\IGSASCEWGSHARDY\Common Services\Data Management Unit\Surface Water\Field Notes (historic)\*") do (
    for /d %%j in ("D:\DataArchive\Surface Water\Data Sites\*") do (
        set srcdir="%%~nxi"
        set destdir="%%~nxj"
        if !srcdir! == !destdir! ( echo Same! timeout /t -1 ) else (echo Notsame!)
        echo %srcdir%
        ping 130.11.160.2
    )
)
```

Thanks guys in advance for your help!

*EDIT*

My apologies, I didn't state the bugs: I'm drawing a blank on the looping portion of the Java because by looking at it, I know that it's not right, however I just wanted some ideas on where to go from here; I'd like to keep just a for-loop iteration because I think that recursion would be a little too messy. For the batch implementation, it keeps falsing out and I never get a match even though I know there are files with the same names across both directories

Comment: you are escaping the `"` and though don´t end the `String`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is not working? Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My apologies, basically with the batch file, it always falses out, and with the Java file, I know the coding is pretty garbage, so I wanted to know in what direction should I go

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in your java code:

- `srcDir.length()` returns the length in bytes if the file pointed by srcDir
- same for `destDir`
- if `srcDir.equals(destDir)` is `true` you reset `j` to 0. So it will repeat the same loop infinitely
- `srcDir.equals(destDir)` check for equality of files. They point to two different files, so also this is an error. Probably you need to check the names. Something like `srcDir.getName().equals(destDir.getName())`

Check for this errors and adapt your question once it is updated.

Comment: Alright, so for the length, I implemented the following code:

    Files.list(Paths.get("insert path here")).count();